# Travelling to Saudi Arabia by road in private car

Tags: customs-and-immigration, road-trips, uae, saudi-arabia

I am Abu Dhabi resident, and would like to go on a road trip in private car to Saudi Arabia.

It was restricted earlier, so I would like to know if it's possible now?

Comment: The answer will depend on your nationality and whether you alredy hold a US, UK, or Schengen visa. See [this Saudi page](https://www.visitsaudi.com/en/travel-regulations) for more information.

Comment: I should add that my comment above addresses the unasked "Can I get a visa?" question. I don't know whether Saudi will let you drive into the country, or what might be required to take a vehicle across the border.